# radio button blur event always checked

Tags: jquery

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dvF5d/2/

```
<input type="radio" id="rad1" name="rad"/><label for="rad1">rad1</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1"/><label for="chk1">chk1</label><br/>
<input type="radio" id="rad2" name="rad"/><label for="rad2">rad2</label>

 $(document).ready(function(){
  var rad1 = $('#rad1');
  var chk1 = $('#chk1');
    var a =  function(){
        if(!rad1.is(':checked'))
        {
           chk1.attr('disabled', true);
        }
        console.log('rad checked', rad1.is(':checked'));
    };
    rad1.blur(function(){
        console.log('blur');
         a();     
    });
    rad1.change(function(){
        console.log('change');
        a();
    });
});
```

When rad1 is blurred, the rad1 is checked property is always true even if rad2 is selected. Is there anyway to fix this? (or better yet, some kind of jquery plugin that enables/disables controls based on other controls).

Comment: What exactly is the goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: How do you select rad2 and then blur rad1 without selecting rad1?

Comment: When rad1 is selected, chk1 should be enabled. When rad2 is selected, chk1 should be disabled. The above should work except that in the blur event, the rad1.is('checked') is always true even though rad1 is not selected.

Comment: It works for me, but radio buttons do not receive focus on click, you'll have to tab to it to make it work, as it will not blur just because you clicked, and clicked something else, like any other element would.

Comment: "When rad2 is selected, chk1 should be disabled." Your fiddle doesn't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `blur` in terms of a radio button, the only circumstance that would cause unchecking the radio button, is checking another one. So change your `blur` to be:

```
$("input[type='radio']:not(#rad1)").change(function(){
    //rad1 isn't checked
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dvF5d/4/**

Comment: Radio inputs actually do have an onblur event. This event occurs when the input gains focus and has it removed by tabbing off of the input. It does not, however, fire when another element is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

To toggle the checkbox based on the radio selection:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $rad1 = $('#rad1');
    var $checkbox = $('#chk1');

    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        $checkbox.prop('disabled', !$rad1.is(':checked'));
    });
});​
```

Comment: The keywords are `enables/disables controls based on other controls`

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder - Thanks, I misread OP. The code has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already selected an answer, however based on your comment, "When rad1 is selected, chk1 should be enabled. When rad2 is selected, chk1 should be disabled." the following would do what you said:

```
​$('input[name="rad"]').change(function(){
    $('#chk1').attr('disabled',$('#rad2').is(':checked'));
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dvF5d/5/)**.